# How to delete a key with lodash _.map

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a lodash map function that sometimes has an empty value in the important property of a given key, and in this case I'd like to remove that key from the result entirely. How do I do that?

Tried just `if (_.isEmpty(key.thing)) { delete key }` but this didn't work - it actually broke the app.

Comment: can you post the full `_.map` statement with the dodgy `if` included? [`_.forEach`](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) may be a better option

Comment: Not enough information. Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: you can't delete variables only properties on objects

Comment: Really, there's not enough information? You iterate through an object with _.map and encounter keys which do not have any values in them, and want to remove them. How complicated can this get?

Comment: As far as I know forEach doesn't return a result, which is what I need to do, iterate through a collection and perform many different operations on each key, winding up with a new object at the end. I suppose I could just manually assign it at the end of each forEach loop, though

Comment: Not enough information guy is really getting upvotes on this? The situation is totally plain....

Comment: AFAIK you can't really choose not to return a value for an entry, it will probably just store `undefined` in the result array. I would go for `_.foreach` and manually [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to a result array in the iterator function.

Comment: If you want to throw that in an answer I'll accept it @Rhumborl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reduce` function and filter empty values there.

```
_.reduce(yourArray, function(result, currentItem) {
  var itemAfterSomeOperations;

  if (!_.isEmpty(currentItem.thing)) {
    //here you can do any operations like in your _.map handler function 
    //and then push the updated item after your operations in the resulted array

    itemAfterSomeOperations = someOperationOnItemAndReturnNewValue(currentItem);

    result.push(itemAfterSomeOperations);
  }

  return result;
}, []);
```

You don't need to delete key, since `_.map` as well as `_.reduce` will return new array with any items you would like.
Please, keep in mind that `map`, `filter`, `find` etc can be implemented with `reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

what you describe is filtering, not mapping.

```
_.filter(yourArray, function(v){ return !_.isEmpty(v.thing)});
```

> > Yeah, but what I'm talking about is doing this in the same breath as many other operations.

Then use reduce

```
_.reduce(yourArray, function(out, v){
    if(!_.isEmpty(v.thing)){
        //process you data and push some value 
        //to the output if you like
        out.push(mapingFunction(v));
    }
    return out;
}, []);
```

Comment: Yeah, but what I'm talking about is doing this in the same breath as many other operations. I wanted to be able to do them in the same function, but maybe I'll just have to do two.